# select top max rows which has sum = 50 in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my dataframe

```
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
|           _c3|sum(number)|              perc|
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
|        France|    5170305|1.3201573334529797|
|       Germany|    9912088|2.5308982087190754|
|       Vietnam|   14729566| 3.760966630301244|
|United Kingdom|   19435674| 4.962598446648971|
|   Philippines|   21994132| 5.615861086093151|
|         Japan|   35204549| 8.988936539189615|
|         China|   39453426|10.073821498682275|
|     Hong Kong|   39666589|  10.1282493704753|
|      Thailand|   57202857|14.605863902228613|
|      Malaysia|   72364309| 18.47710593603423|
|     Indonesia|   76509597|19.535541048174547|
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I want to select only top countries which sum up to 50 percent of passengers (country, number of passengers, percentage of passengers). How can I do it?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? We're not here to write code for you but to help you when you have a concrete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a running total to store cumulative percentage and then filter by it. So, assuming your dataframe is small enough, something like this should do it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val result = df.withColumn("cumulativepercentage", sum("perc").over(
                  Window.orderBy(col("perc").desc))
               ).where(col("cumulativepercentage").leq(50))
result.show(false)
```

Comment: Great. For future reference https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html

Comment: Thank You so much :)